# SpriteKit - Check contact against any object

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

in Spritekit when you want to check if an object contacted another and perform some actions you have to use this to specify the object:

```
physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ?????
```

But what if I want to test against any object in the scene? I don't want to specify certain objects, but I do want to know if a contact has happened.

Comment: contactTestBitMask is not used for certain objects,  it is used to classify if a particular object is contactable with the given object.  Thus you can have 100 balls on the screen all sharing the same categoryBitMask called ball,  and when a bat hits any of those 100 balls, did contact will fire,  so if you want all contacts to be tested.  set the contact bit mask to 0xFFFF,  this means that all categories will register contact.

Comment: what if the balls have different categoryBitMasks ?

Comment: I hit enter before finishing my comment. (was trying to get a new line, force of habit),  see my edit to it

Comment: Will try that. Thanks.